# Local Database for Java application

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx-8

I have a client server based application.
The server is PHP with MySQL, no big functionality, just for keeping my data and providing and administration interface.
The client is a Java (FX) application.

Unfortunately the connection between the client and server is not permanent, so  I have to have a local copy of the database for the case the server if not accessible.
Most of the times the client only reads data from the database but there are a few cases when it needs to update it.

My question is: what is the better solution to keep up a local copy of a MySQL database and track changes (to be updated in MySQL next time it is available).

It is a complicator factor that I do not need the full database locally, it would be too large, I need only the user specific information (user is authenticated by local machine username)

Do you have any idea? :)

Thanks:
Levente

Comment: If you want to periodically update a local MySQL database based on some other MySQL database, then I think this is the realm of MySQL and not really Java.

Comment: I might keep a database for reading only, but I would not make any updates exclusively on the client side and then try and sync those to the server.  Can you use a message queuing system to hold on to update requests until the server becomes available again?  Also, how much data does the client need - enough to justify having a client-side database, or can you just keep it in memory when the app starts?

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstandable. I do not have a local MySQL database, I am not able to install any prerequisites on client machine.

Comment: The amount of data is not too much, user assignments (about 10-20 entry for one user) results (100-200 entry for one user).